# C# - XML deserialization - ignore elements with attribue

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I need to deserialize some xml to c# objects. This is my class:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
[Serializable]
public class MyRoot
{        
    [XmlElement("category")]
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

I'm deserializing like this:

```
root = (MyRoot)new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyRoot)).Deserialize(new StringReader(client.DownloadString(XmlUrl)));
```

But I want to ignore some Category elements with specified "id" attribute values. Is there some way I can do this?

Comment: Simply post-process deserialized object (go through list, check id and remove). If you can't do that, then please explain why.

Comment: Is this a one way street or do you need to deserialize the XML later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing `IXmlSerializable` is one way to go, but perhaps an easier path would be simply modifying the XML (using LINQ or XSLT?) ahead of time:

```
HashSet<string> badIds = new HashSet<string>();
badIds.Add("1");
badIds.Add("excludeme");
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(client.DownloadString(XmlUrl)));
var badCategories = xd.Root.Descendants("category").Where(x => badIds.Contains((string)x.Attribute("id")));
if (badCategories != null && badCategories.Any())
  badCategories.Remove();
MyRoot root = (MyRoot)new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyRoot)).Deserialize(xd.Root.CreateReader());
```

You could do something similar on your resulting collection, but it's entirely possible you don't serialize the `id`, and may not want to/need to otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! I was just wondering, if there is some c# attribute to do this

Comment: Nope.  Not without custom `IXmlSerializable`

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to have a property named something like ImportCategories with the [XmlElement("category")] attribute and then have Categories as a property that returns a filtered list from ImportCategories using LINQ.

Then your code would do the deserialisaion and then use root.Categories.

Answer (score 1):

To do this the Microsoft way, you would need to implement an `IXmlSerializable` interface for the class that you want to serialize:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx

It's going to require some hand-coding on your part - you basically have to implement the `WriteXml` and `ReadXml` methods, and you get a `XmlWriter` and a `XmlReader` interface respectively, to do what you need to do.

Just remember to keep your classes pretty atomic, so that you don't end up custom-serializing for the entire object graph (ugh).